# react-table version 7 onSortedChange callback equivalent

Tags: react-table

I'm trying to migrate to react-table version 7 https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table. My existing code has a callback for `onSortedChange` but I can't figure out how to replicate this with the new version 7 hooks.

Version 6 format:

```
<ReactTable
  onSortedChange={myCallbackFn}
/>
```

Version 7:

```
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
} = useTable(
    {
        columns,
        data,
        defaultColumn,
        filterTypes
    },
    useFilters,
    useSortBy
);
...
```

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

I spent a couple hours trying to do this, then figured it out 2 minutes after posting my question.

```
const { state: { sortBy }} = useTable(...)

React.useEffect(() => {
  // `sortBy` changed
}, [sortBy])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for jumping in but I'm curious if you got this to work fully. I have the same issue as you except for filtering and following your solution I still don't get it to work.

I do:

```
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    sortBy,
    filterBy,
} = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
    defaultColumn,
    filterTypes,
},
    useFilters,
    useSortBy

)

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('sort by changed: '+sortBy);
  }, [sortBy])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('filter by changed');
  }, [filterBy])
```

And I get both logs at initial load/render of my table but nothing more, no logs when I sort or filter my table. Did you do anything more which you didn't post?

Comment: Jola - In your example `sortBy` and `filterBy` are destructured directly from the returned table instance. Instead try destructuring from the `state` object within the returned instance (see the top of my working answer). I haven't tested with filters, but I would guess something like: `state: { sortBy, filterBy }`

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! Works fine, with the change that `filterBy` doesn't exist, it's called `filters`.